# Release Pipeline Azure DevOps, EfCore Migration Bundle

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm pretty new at working with pipelines, but in any case I'm attempting to apply EFcore migration bundle on Azure DevOps.

I'm able to create the bundle in a build pipeline and then publish the efcore bundle file as an artifact:

```
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/server/efbundle
  artifact: efbundle
```

However when I try to run the efbundle in a release pipeline it doesn't work.. Actually it doesn't really do anything at all. The only thing I notice is that it creates an Orphan Process.

I use powershell and run this command

```
./efcore --connection '[ConnectionString]'
```

If I run that same command on the build pipeline however.. it works fine, so I wonder if there something wrong with the way I'm publishing the artifact, or is there possibly something else missing?

I appreciate any ideas you might have to help with this :)

Thanks

Comment: Add --verbose to diagnose

Comment: Thanks, I have done that. Nothing appears when I add verbose. 

If I run the command in the build stage I get this:

No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
Done.


However if I run the same command in the release 
I get absolutely nothing No error! or anything.

The only difference I assume is that i published the bundle as an artifact.

Comment: did you solve this @SirJames can the bundle be run if you download it from a artifact?